# PyCharm IDE: boto is already installed but got a "No module named boto.cloudfront" importError

Tags: python-2.7, pycharm

I have already got boto installed to my python virtual environment, as shown in the screenshot of my pycharm project.

[image]

However I got an `ImportError` of boto.cloudfront when I run my script from pycharm

```
ERROR    2015-04-20 00:17:39,590 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/antkong/dev/test/testmain.py", line 7, in <module>
    from boto.cloudfront import CloudFrontConnection
ImportError: No module named boto.cloudfront
```

In the python console, I can import the library just fine:

[image]

Any suggestion what can go wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project is a Google App Engine project. So even though boto is installed locally, it is not visible to my code within my Google App Engine project

My solution is to copy the boto and all dependency into a `lib` subdirectory and then add it to the `sys.path`